# How to fix the MPI_Gatherv problem with 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, mpi

First question in the community, if there is anything wrong about my format, please tell me.

I am using MPI_Gatherv to collect data. I may have to collect something like vector<vector>. I heard MPI_Gatherv can only do with vector, so I decide to send the data vector by vector. Below is the example of my idea. However, it failed in the MPI_Finalize(), and it said 0xC0000005. If I delete the MPI_Gatherv(&c,count.at(i),MPI_INT,&temre,&count.at(i),displs,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD), it worked. I wonder whether it has something to do with the address conflicts.
Thanks for any help!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int gsize;
    int myrank;

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &gsize);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

    vector<vector<int>> a,reci;
    vector<int> count(1,10);
    vector<int> b(10,1),NU(1,0);
    a.push_back(b);
    reci.push_back(NU);
    for ( int i = 0; i < myrank*3+2; i++ )
    {
        b.push_back(i); 
        count.push_back(11+i);
        a.push_back(b);
        reci.push_back(NU);
    }

    vector<int> c,temre(1,1);
    int displs[1]={0};

    for ( int i = 0; i < myrank*3+3; i++ )
    {
        c = a.at(i);
        MPI_Gatherv(&c,count.at(i),MPI_INT,
            &temre,&count.at(i),displs,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        reci.at(i).swap(temre);
    }

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks for any comments and answers.
After several days working, I found out the error. For vectors in MPI, you must use &c[0] instead of &c in
`MPI_Gatherv(&c,count.at(i),MPI_INT, &temre,&count.at(i),displs,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);`(also &temre[0] instead of &temre)

However, currently it can work in Serial, but not parallel. I am trying to fix the problem and put the executable code.
Thanks again for any help!

Comment: The first loop has `myrank*3+2` as the limiting value, but the second loop has `myrank*3+3` as the limiting value.  If they are supposed to be the same, use a constant, not a magic "formula" that can lead to typos, or use `vector::size()` to ensure that the value is correct.

Comment: `displs` should be an array of (at least) `gsize` integers, and `temre` should be large enough to hold all the elements sent by all the processes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, you are right. At first, I just tried to build a simple code to let the program run. I fix these potential problems in my final codes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that MPI is strictly a C library. So you can not directly send/recv with a `std::vector` as buffer. Your buffer has to be an `int*` or whatever type you use. So in your case: `MPI_Gatherv(c.data(),...`

Comment: I am not very sure, I notice some programs could do this, I am trying to figure out how they do it.

Comment: I kinda doubt it. Unless they use `std::array`.